# How to reload fetch data from coredata in Intent Handler when host App close?

Tags: swiftui, widgetkit, intents-extension

I'm currently developing an application using SwiftUI.

I want to reload data from CoreData in `IntentHandler` to update newer data every when I close a host App.

In the case of `Widget`, we can use `WidgetCenter.shared.reloadAllTimelines()` to update, but how can we update data in the case of `IntentHandler`?

In my codes, data in a list of editing view in the widget receive data only when the host app boots for the first time.

---

Here are the codes:

TimerApp.swift (Host APP)

```
import SwiftUI
import WidgetKit

@main
struct TimerApp: App {
    @Environment(\.scenePhase) private var scenePhase
    
    let persistenceController = PersistenceController.shared.managedObjectContext
    
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView()
                .environment(\.managedObjectContext, persistenceController)
                .onChange(of: scenePhase) { newScenePhase in
                    if newScenePhase == .inactive {
                       // I want to update a data in IntentHandler here
                    }
                }
        }
    }
}
```

IntentHandler.swift (IntentsExtension)

```
import WidgetKit
import SwiftUI
import CoreData
import Intents

class IntentHandler: INExtension, ConfigurationIntentHandling {
    
    var moc = PersistenceController.shared.managedObjectContext

    var timerEntity:TimerEntity?
   
    func provideNameOptionsCollection(for intent: ConfigurationIntent, searchTerm: String?, with completion: @escaping (INObjectCollection<NSString>?, Error?) -> Void) {
        
        let request = NSFetchRequest<TimerEntity>(entityName: "TimerEntity")

        do{
            let result = try moc.fetch(request)
            timerEntity = result.first
        }
        catch let error as NSError{
            print("Could not fetch.\(error.userInfo)")
        }
        
        let nameIdentifiers:[NSString] = [
            NSString(string: timerEntity?.task ?? ""),
        ]
        
        
        let allNameIdentifiers = INObjectCollection(items: nameIdentifiers)
        
        completion(allNameIdentifiers,nil)
    }
    
    override func handler(for intent: INIntent) -> Any {
        
        return self
    }
}
```

---

Xcode: Version 12.0.1

iOS: 14.0

Life Cycle: SwiftUI App

Comment: One year later.... Did you find any solution?

Comment: @Alirezak Not yet ...

Comment: I could solve my problem without any change! actually I think it is a bug. when you test your app in debug mode, the debugger stops the core data to be updated from external events (e.g Siri intent). When I stop debugger, my list will show new data